Spring Boot Prometheus PushGatewayManager: Unable to push metrics due to SocketTimeoutException
I'm encountering an issue with my Spring Boot application where it fails to push metrics to Prometheus Pushgateway. The issue is happening intermettently
The error message indicates a SocketTimeoutException. Below is the relevant part of the stack trace:
org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.export.prometheus.PrometheusPushGatewayManager$PushGatewayTaskScheduler:218 - Shutting down ExecutorService
2024-07-01T17:12:03,782 ERROR org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.export.prometheus.PrometheusPushGatewayManager:119 - Unable to push metrics to Prometheus Pushgateway
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_392]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116) ~[?:1.8.0_392]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171) ~[?:1.8.0_392]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[?:1.8.0_392]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246) ~[?:1.8.0_392]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286) ~[?:1.8.0_392]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345) ~[?:1.8.0_392]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:743) ~[?:1.8.0_392]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:678) ~[?:1.8.0_392]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1595) ~[?:1.8.0_392]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1500) ~[?:1.8.0_392]
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480) ~[?:1.8.0_392]
    at io.prometheus.client.exporter.PushGateway.doRequest(PushGateway.java:315) ~[hadoop-unjar3434452571338587139/:?]
    at io.prometheus.client.exporter.PushGateway.pushAdd(PushGateway.java:182) ~[hadoop-unjar3434452571338587139/:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.export.prometheus.PrometheusPushGatewayManager.push(PrometheusPushGatewayManager.java:108) ~[hadoop-unjar3434452571338587139/:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.export.prometheus.PrometheusPushGatewayManager.shutdown(PrometheusPushGatewayManager.java:146) ~[hadoop-unjar3434452571338587139/:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.export.prometheus.PrometheusPushGatewayManager.shutdown(PrometheusPushGatewayManager.java:136) ~[hadoop-unjar3434452571338587139/:?]
    ...


My Reporter class
package com.hotels.bdp.cloverleaf.metrics;

import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import io.micrometer.core.instrument.Counter;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.ImmutableTag;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.Tag;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.Tags;

/**
 * MetricReporterService is responsible for reporting metrics to configured meter registries,
 * including Graphite and Prometheus. It manages a collection of metrics and tags, and
 * provides methods to report both general and partition-specific metrics.
 *
 * The class utilizes Micrometer's MeterRegistry to register and send metrics.
 * It supports adding metrics with or without partition tags, and ensures metrics are
 * properly tagged before reporting.
 */
public class MetricReporterService {
  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MetricReporterService.class);
  private static final String PARTITION_TAG_KEY = "partition";
  private final MeterRegistry meterRegistry;
  private final List<Metric> metrics = new ArrayList<>();
  private final Map<Metric, String> partitionMetrics = new HashMap<>();
  private final Tags tags;

  private final ScheduledExecutorService executorService;

  @Autowired
  public MetricReporterService(MeterRegistry meterRegistry, List<ImmutableTag> cloverleafTags) {
    this.meterRegistry = meterRegistry;
    this.tags = Tags.of(cloverleafTags);

    // Initialize the executor service with a single thread
    this.executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(r -> {
      Thread thread = new Thread(r);
      thread.setDaemon(true); // Daemon thread so it doesn't prevent JVM shutdown
      thread.setName("metric-reporter");
      return thread;
    });

    // Schedule the task to report metrics every fixed interval
    this.executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(this::reportAllMetrics, 0, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
  }

  public void addMetric(Metric metric) {
    metrics.add(metric);
  }

  public void addPartitionMetric(Metric metric, String partition) {
    partitionMetrics.put(metric, partition);
  }

  /**
   * Reports all the metrics to the meter registry, including both general and partition-specific metrics.
   */
  public void reportAllMetrics() {
    metrics.forEach(this::reportSingleMetric);

    partitionMetrics.forEach((metric, partition) -> {
      try {
        reportPartitionedMetric(metric, partition);
      } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        log.error("SocketTimeoutException while reporting partition metric '{}'", metric.getName(), e);
      }  catch (RuntimeException e) {
        log.error("RuntimeException while reporting partition metric '{}'", metric.getName(), e);
      }
    });
  }

  private void reportSingleMetric(Metric metric) {
    int retryCount = 0;
    int maxRetries = 3; // Adjust as needed
    long timeout = 1000; // Initial timeout in milliseconds

    while (retryCount < maxRetries) {
      try {
        report(metric, tags);
        return; // Success, exit loop
      } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        // Handle timeout specifically
        log.warn("Failed to report metric '{}' on attempt {} due to timeout. Retrying...", metric.getName(), retryCount + 1, e);
        retryCount++;
        timeout *= 2; // Exponential backoff
        try {
          Thread.sleep(timeout);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
          // Handle being interrupted during sleep (optional)
          log.warn("Thread interrupted while waiting for retry. Continuing...", ie);
        }
      } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        log.error("RuntimeException while reporting metric '{}'", metric.getName(), e);
        return; // Exit loop on other runtime exceptions
      }
    }
    log.error("Failed to report metric '{}' after {} retries.", metric.getName(), maxRetries);
  }

  private void reportPartitionedMetric(Metric metric, String partition) throws SocketTimeoutException {
    try {
      report(metric, tags.and(PARTITION_TAG_KEY, partition));
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
      log.error("SocketTimeoutException while reporting partition metric '{}'", metric.getName(), e);
      // Retry logic not explicitly handled here, ensure control flow reaches reportSingleMetric
      throw e; // Rethrow to ensure it propagates up the call stack
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
      log.error("RuntimeException while reporting partition metric '{}'", metric.getName(), e);
    }
  }

  private void report(Metric metric, Iterable<Tag> tags) throws SocketTimeoutException {
    String metricName = metric.getName();
    double metricValue = metric.getValue();

    // Register the metric with the configured meter registry
    Counter counter = Counter.builder(metricName).tags(tags).register(meterRegistry);

    log.info("\nSuccessfully recorded metric '{}' with value {} and tags {}\n",
        metricName,
        metricValue,
        tags);

    counter.increment(metricValue);
  }

  // Ensure the executor service shuts down gracefully on application shutdown
  public void shutdown() {
    log.info("Shutting down MetricReporterService...");

    executorService.shutdown();
    try {
      if (!executorService.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
        log.warn("Executor service did not terminate in time. Attempting forced shutdown...");
        executorService.shutdownNow();
        if (!executorService.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
          log.error("Executor service could not be terminated.");
        }
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      log.error("Interrupted while waiting for executor service termination.", e);
      executorService.shutdownNow();
      Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    log.info("MetricReporterService shutdown complete.");
  }
}


My PushGateway Deployment in Kubernetes
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: prometheus-pushgateway
  namespace: monitoring
  uid: 0e452c81
  resourceVersion: '1316386'
  generation: 14
  creationTimestamp: '2023-11-21T21:39:50Z'
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: prometheus-pushgateway
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: prometheus-pushgateway
    app.kubernetes.io/version: v1.5.1
    helm.sh/chart: prometheus-pushgateway-2.0.3
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: '11'
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: prometheus-pushgateway
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: monitoring
  managedFields:
    - manager: Go-http-client
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: apps/v1
      time: '2024-06-24T22:04:13Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        'f:metadata':
          'f:annotations':
            .: {}
            'f:meta.helm.sh/release-name': {}
            'f:meta.helm.sh/release-namespace': {}
          'f:labels':
            .: {}
            'f:app.kubernetes.io/instance': {}
            'f:app.kubernetes.io/managed-by': {}
            'f:app.kubernetes.io/name': {}
            'f:app.kubernetes.io/version': {}
            'f:helm.sh/chart': {}
        'f:spec':
          'f:progressDeadlineSeconds': {}
          'f:revisionHistoryLimit': {}
          'f:selector': {}
          'f:strategy':
            'f:type': {}
          'f:template':
            'f:metadata':
              'f:annotations':
                .: {}
                'f:eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn': {}
              'f:labels':
                .: {}
                'f:app.kubernetes.io/instance': {}
                'f:app.kubernetes.io/managed-by': {}
                'f:app.kubernetes.io/name': {}
                'f:app.kubernetes.io/version': {}
                'f:helm.sh/chart': {}
            'f:spec':
              'f:containers':
                'k:{"name":"pushgateway"}':
                  .: {}
                  'f:image': {}
                  'f:imagePullPolicy': {}
                  'f:livenessProbe':
                    .: {}
                    'f:failureThreshold': {}
                    'f:httpGet':
                      .: {}
                      'f:path': {}
                      'f:port': {}
                      'f:scheme': {}
                    'f:initialDelaySeconds': {}
                    'f:periodSeconds': {}
                    'f:successThreshold': {}
                  'f:name': {}
                  'f:ports':
                    .: {}
                    'k:{"containerPort":9091,"protocol":"TCP"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:containerPort': {}
                      'f:name': {}
                      'f:protocol': {}
                  'f:readinessProbe':
                    .: {}
                    'f:failureThreshold': {}
                    'f:httpGet':
                      .: {}
                      'f:path': {}
                      'f:port': {}
                      'f:scheme': {}
                    'f:initialDelaySeconds': {}
                    'f:periodSeconds': {}
                    'f:successThreshold': {}
                  'f:resources': {}
                  'f:terminationMessagePath': {}
                  'f:terminationMessagePolicy': {}
                  'f:volumeMounts':
                    .: {}
                    'k:{"mountPath":"/data"}':
                      .: {}
                      'f:mountPath': {}
                      'f:name': {}
              'f:dnsPolicy': {}
              'f:imagePullSecrets':
                .: {}
                'k:{"name":"artifactory-hub-docker-remote"}': {}
              'f:restartPolicy': {}
              'f:schedulerName': {}
              'f:securityContext':
                .: {}
                'f:fsGroup': {}
                'f:runAsNonRoot': {}
                'f:runAsUser': {}
              'f:serviceAccount': {}
              'f:serviceAccountName': {}
              'f:terminationGracePeriodSeconds': {}
              'f:volumes':
                .: {}
                'k:{"name":"storage-volume"}':
                  .: {}
                  'f:name': {}
                  'f:persistentVolumeClaim':
                    .: {}
                    'f:claimName': {}
    - manager: dashboard
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: apps/v1
      time: '2024-06-28T12:03:48Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        'f:spec':
          'f:replicas': {}
          'f:template':
            'f:metadata':
              'f:annotations':
                'f:ad.datadoghq.com/pushgateway.check_names': {}
                'f:ad.datadoghq.com/pushgateway.init_configs': {}
                'f:ad.datadoghq.com/pushgateway.instances': {}
                'f:prometheus.io/path': {}
                'f:prometheus.io/port': {}
                'f:prometheus.io/scrape': {}
            'f:spec':
              'f:containers':
                'k:{"name":"pushgateway"}':
                  'f:livenessProbe':
                    'f:timeoutSeconds': {}
                  'f:readinessProbe':
                    'f:timeoutSeconds': {}
    - manager: kube-controller-manager
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: apps/v1
      time: '2024-07-01T18:19:37Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        'f:metadata':
          'f:annotations':
            'f:deployment.kubernetes.io/revision': {}
        'f:status':
          'f:availableReplicas': {}
          'f:conditions':
            .: {}
            'k:{"type":"Available"}':
              .: {}
              'f:lastTransitionTime': {}
              'f:lastUpdateTime': {}
              'f:message': {}
              'f:reason': {}
              'f:status': {}
              'f:type': {}
            'k:{"type":"Progressing"}':
              .: {}
              'f:lastTransitionTime': {}
              'f:lastUpdateTime': {}
              'f:message': {}
              'f:reason': {}
              'f:status': {}
              'f:type': {}
          'f:observedGeneration': {}
          'f:readyReplicas': {}
          'f:replicas': {}
          'f:updatedReplicas': {}
      subresource: status
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: prometheus-pushgateway
      app.kubernetes.io/name: prometheus-pushgateway
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: prometheus-pushgateway
        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
        app.kubernetes.io/name: prometheus-pushgateway
        app.kubernetes.io/version: v1.5.1
        helm.sh/chart: prometheus-pushgateway-2.0.3
      annotations:
        ad.datadoghq.com/pushgateway.check_names: '["openmetrics"]'
        ad.datadoghq.com/pushgateway.init_configs: '[{}]'
        ad.datadoghq.com/pushgateway.instances: >-
          [{ "prometheus_url": "http://%%host%%:9091/metrics", "namespace":
          "cloverleaf", "metrics": [
          "current_lag*","jvm_*","system_*","timer_*","backfill_lag*","partition*","populate_temp_tables*","push*","source*","touched_partition*","triggered_by*","update_table*","triggered*","schema_evolutio*","input-parti*","bytes*","new_partition*","touched*","modified*","source*","update*","populate*","execution*",
          "long_running_jobs_killed*" , "update-table-statistics-duration*"   ],
          "max_returned_metrics":"30000"  }]
        eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: 'arn:....'
        prometheus.io/path: /metrics
        prometheus.io/port: '9091'
        prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: storage-volume
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: prometheus-pushgateway
      containers:
        - name: pushgateway
          image: 'hub-docker-remote.artylab.expedia.biz/prom/pushgateway:v1.0.1'
          ports:
            - name: metrics
              containerPort: 9091
              protocol: TCP
          resources: {}
          volumeMounts:
            - name: storage-volume
              mountPath: /data
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /-/ready
              port: 9091
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 30
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 3
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /-/ready
              port: 9091
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 30
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 3
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      restartPolicy: Always
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      serviceAccountName: prometheus-pushgateway
      serviceAccount: prometheus-pushgateway
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 65534
        runAsNonRoot: true
        fsGroup: 65534
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: artifactory-hub-docker-remote
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
status:
  observedGeneration: 14
  replicas: 1
  updatedReplicas: 1
  readyReplicas: 1
  availableReplicas: 1
  conditions:
    - type: Progressing
      status: 'True'
      lastUpdateTime: '2024-06-27T21:09:03Z'
      lastTransitionTime: '2023-11-21T21:39:50Z'
      reason: NewReplicaSetAvailable
      message: >-
        ReplicaSet "prometheus-pushgateway-6db8" has successfully
        progressed.
    - type: Available
      status: 'True'
      lastUpdateTime: '2024-07-01T18:19:37Z'
      lastTransitionTime: '2024-07-01T18:19:37Z'
      reason: MinimumReplicasAvailable
      message: Deployment has minimum availability.


What I’ve Tried
Network Issues: Verified that the Pushgateway is accessible from the application server.
Timeout Settings: Checked and adjusted timeout settings to see if it mitigates the issue.
.properties("management.metrics.export.prometheus.pushgateway.connect-timeout=20s") .properties("management.metrics.export.prometheus.pushgateway.read-timeout=40s")
Questions

What could be causing the SocketTimeoutException when pushing metrics to Prometheus Pushgateway?
Are there any specific configurations in Spring Boot or Prometheus Pushgateway that I might be missing or need to adjust?
Could there be any underlying network or resource constraints contributing to this issue?
Any guidance or suggestions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

